# Jquery datepicker and php datetime don't agree?

Tags: php, jquery, datetime, datepicker

I'm trying to do something that seems like it should be simple, but somehow won't tie up properly.

The user selects a date from a [jquery datepicker](https://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/), where I have `showWeek` enabled.

```
$(".datepicker").datepicker({
    showWeek: true,
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd'
});
```

But, when the resulting date string is fed into a php datetime, the week does not correspond, and is 1 week further into the future.

```
$start_date = isset($_POST['startdate']) ? $_POST['startdate'] : "";
$start = new DateTime($start_date);
echo $start->format("W");
```

IE, 2018-10-02 shows as week 39 in my datepicker, but the echo above from reading that date back into a datetime and formatting for week returns week 40.

So, as far as I can tell, the jquery datepicker and php datetime class do not agree on which weeks are which by default.

Is there a way to reconcile this?

The PHP [date](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) says it conforms to ISO-8601, [Checking online](https://www.epochconverter.com/weeknumbers) confirms for me that php has it right, so how do I fix the datepicker to display correctly?

Comment: What datepicker are you using because there are a lots of libraries out there

Comment: heh, the datepicker documentation ( [`calculateWeek`](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-calculateWeek) ) also claims to be using the ISO-8601. I _think_ that there is a bug with datepicker.

Comment: @sigma I've added a link, I'm using the standard jquery datepicker widget

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok here is the solution: according to jquery ui you need to specify the first day and in your code you are missing it:

```html
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>jQuery UI Datepicker - Show week of the year</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script>
  $( function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
      showWeek: true,
      firstDay: 1,
      changeMonth: true,
      changeYear: true,
      dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd'
    });
  } );
  </script>
</head>
<body>
 
<p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker"></p>
 
 
</body>
```

Just add firstDay: 1, and everything works as you expect.

Comment: Beautiful, thankyou. Trying to understand why it works though... It sets the first day displayed in a row to Monday whereas default was Sunday. The row displays the week of the first day in the row, hence the discrepancy? I'm surprised that jQuery doesn't default to Monday to avoid this issue!

Comment: According to the documentation and the api you must set the first day of the week. Sunday is 0, Monday is 1, etc.. Take a look here: http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-firstDay and this is the explanation from jquery official page: The datepicker can show the week of the year. The default calculation follows the ISO 8601 definition: the week starts on Monday, the first week of the year contains the first Thursday of the year. This means that some days from one year may be placed into weeks 'belonging' to another year. Seems complicated but at the end there is a nice logic on it :)